# PHPExcel Multiple Dropdown list that dependent

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to set up multiple dropdowns in phpexcel that are dependent. Basically, when you select a value in a dropdown in a column A, it loads different content in the dropdown in column B.

I am able to comfortably set up dropdown lists on cells. I am trying to figure out how to load content based on selection of one dropdown.

Any feedback or solutions or guide will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you figure out how to achieve what you want in MS Excel itself?

Comment: Yes. Found this handy guide http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well I managed to figure it out. Here's the gist for anyone in the future:

Best to use Named Ranges. Basically define before hand the list items (named ranges) in cells. this can be on a different worksheet. So, lets use an example of countries and cities. dropdown 1 will have counties, dropdown 2 will have cities. So define the named ranges. One will be called countries. the other two named ranges will be called after the name of the countries. so, lets go.

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("A1", "UK");
    $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("A2", "USA");

    $objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( 
        new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
            'countries', 
            $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1'), 
            'A1:A2'
        ) 
    );

$objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("B1", "London");
    $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("B2", "Birmingham");
    $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("B3", "Leeds");
    $objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( 
        new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
            'UK', 
            $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1'), 
            'B1:B3'
        ) 
    );

$objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("C1", "Atlanta");
    $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("C2", "New York");
    $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1')->SetCellValue("C3", "Los Angeles");
    $objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( 
        new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
            'USA', 
            $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet 1'), 
            'C1:C3'
        ) 
    );
```

So thats the named ranges. One is the country, the others are the ranges for the cities for each of the countries. Now to load up the first dropdown to select the countries.

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
    $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
    $objValidation->setFormula1("=countries"); //note this!
```

Now for the dropdown to load the cities depending on the country. This uses an excel function called Indirect. Basically returns the selected value. hence the similarly named ranges. so i select "UK", it loads the named range called "UK" which has the UK cities.

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B1')->getDataValidation();
    $objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
    $objValidation->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
    $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list.');
    $objValidation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
    $objValidation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
    $objValidation->setFormula1('=INDIRECT($A$1)');
```

Notes: I have used two sheets. Worksheet 1 to hold the data and sheet 0 or default to hold the dropdowns. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for providing a detailed answer that it will be useful to point anybody else toward if they ask the same question; I'll try to provide an example of this with the next release of PHPExcel

Comment: @MarkBaker Sir how can I pass my array into it. I am fetching the data from database and want to export it as excel. How can I pass this array in this.

Answer (score 0):

Great answer, just one little thing to fix:

When pass the cell in getCell(**'A1'**)->getDataValidation() It should be **'A0'** instead.
Same for getCell(**'B1'**)->getDataValidation(); Should be **'B0'** to prevent conflicts between selection and data.

**EDIT:** What to do if I want to make cities also a list and dependent to, for example, another list called neighborhoods?

Many thanks!