# How to create drop down list in excel using laravel-excel or phpspreadsheet?

Tags: excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

I am using laravel-excel 3.0 in my laravel project and i am unable to create drop-down list while downloading the list.

Below is Export class code

```
 class MasterFields implements FromView
 {
    public function view(): View
{
    return view('master-fields', [
        'master_fields' =>  [
            [
              'name' => 'Povilas',
              'surname' => 'Korop',
              'email' => 'povilas@laraveldaily.com',
              'twitter' => ['@povilaskorop', 'test', 'test']
            ],
            [
              'name' => 'Taylor',
              'surname' => 'Otwell',
              'email' => 'taylor@laravel.com',
              'twitter' => ['@povilaskorop', 'test', 'test']
            ]
          ]
        // MasterDataField::get_master_data_set()
    ]);
  }
  }
```

---

Below is blade code

```
<table>
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th style="color:blue;"><b> ID </b></th>
         <th style="color:blue;"><b> Field Name </b></th>
         <th style="color:blue;"><b> Data Type </b></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody>
     @foreach($master_fields as $field)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $field['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $field['surname'] }}</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                @foreach($field['twitter'] as $twitter)
                <option> {{ $twitter }} </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>


         </td>
     </tr>
     @endforeach
   </tbody>
```

I am using below method to download
     return Excel::download(new MasterFields, 'test.xlsx');

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel excel library(Maatwebsite) : How to create a drop down list in exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815227/laravel-excel-librarymaatwebsite-how-to-create-a-drop-down-list-in-exports)

Comment: I am using 3.0 version and the create method was deprecated. Can you plz suggest me with the latest version of mattwebsite laravel-excel

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the old way of definition doesn't work. But here is an example of the new way: https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-excel-3-0-export-custom-array-excel/

Comment: I have coded the same but, i am unable to create a dropdown

Comment: Can you show us what is the response of : MasterDataField::get_master_data_set()

Comment: [{id: 1, field_name: 'amount' }, {id: 1, field_name: 'description' }, ....]

Comment: Everything looks fine. Can you try with the array from the link instead of calling get_master_data_set() just to be sure it's not about data format

Comment: Cell values are affecting in excel with my code, but when I try to create a dropdown for a cell it is not coming

Comment: Have you tried by replacing the get_master_data_set() with the array from the link just to make sure the array structure is correct?
Do you see an exception?
Can you show us the result in that excel file?

Comment: Yes I have tried by replacing and I have updated the all my code and excel response in the image above, please check.

Comment: Ah I see, can you try instead of select with unordered list https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp

Comment: Ya tried that as well. But giving same result, but not populating as dropdown box.