# maatwebsite laravel excel export columns with drop down list

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I have been using [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com) to export data in csv format and it has been great so far. Now I need to export in xlsx format so that I can include dropdown lists in some of the columns. I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815227/laravel-excel-librarymaatwebsite-how-to-create-a-drop-down-list-in-exports) but it looks like that is for an older version of Laravel Excel.  I also looked at the page in the docs that explains [extending the package](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/extending.html), but I can't seem to figure out how to add a dropdown list to a column while exporting data.

This is a simplified version of my export class:

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;

class ActionItemExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithStrictNullComparison
{

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->getActionItems();
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        $columns = [
            'Column 1',
            'Column 2',
            'Column 3',
            'Column 4',
            'Column 5',
            'Column 6',
            'Column 7'
        ];
        return $columns;
    }

    private function getActionItems()
    {
        $select = 'column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7';

        $query = \DB::table('action_items')->select(\DB::raw($select));
        $query->whereNull('action_items.deleted_at');

        $ai = $query->orderBy('column1')->get();
        return $ai;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is query a lookup table that has the options for column1 and use those values for a drop down list in the column so that when a user wants to change the excel sheet, they are limited to only the drop down values.

In the docs it mentions to use `\Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet` or `\Maatwebsite\Excel\Writer`, but I'm not even sure where to use those at, or which one to use.

Throughout my searches I just can't seem to piece together a solution so any help would be appreciated.

I'm using:

maatwebsite/excel 3.1,
php 7.2,
laravel 5.8

Comment: You want something like this? https://imgur.com/a/lwnSa02

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The implementation of sheet events can be rather confusing and hard to find examples for, so I try to lend a hand when I see a post like this.  First, I'll say you should really be looking at the [PHPSpreadsheet documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for these additional features.  It's where you're going to find the important information you need.  Then you can translate what you find for use in [Laravel Excel](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/).

**PHPSpreadsheet: Setting data validation on a cell**
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell

Here is an example building upon your existing file. I also threw in some bonus formatting to autosize the column widths — a must in my opinion.

```php
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation;

class ActionItemExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithEvents, WithStrictNullComparison
{
    protected $results;

    public function collection()
    {
        // store the results for later use
        $this->results = $this->getActionItems();

        return $this->results;
    }

    // ...

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // handle by a closure.
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {

                // get layout counts (add 1 to rows for heading row)
                $row_count = $this->results->count() + 1;
                $column_count = count($this->results[0]->toArray());

                // set dropdown column
                $drop_column = 'A';

                // set dropdown options
                $options = [
                    'option 1',
                    'option 2',
                    'option 3',
                ];

                // set dropdown list for first data row
                $validation = $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_column}2")->getDataValidation();
                $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                $validation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from list');
                $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation->setFormula1(sprintf('"%s"',implode(',',$options)));

                // clone validation to remaining rows
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("{$drop_column}{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
                }

                // set columns to autosize
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $column_count; $i++) {
                    $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
                    $event->sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.  I think the Laravel Excel docs needs more examples like this.

Comment: is there a limit of numbers you can add to dropdown options?

Comment: According to online sources, Excel has (or had at one time) [limits of 32,767 items and 256 characters per item](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_365hp/what-is-limit-of-the-number-of-entries-in-excel/9ce4a909-8b03-428f-94a4-1b13433aa399) in a dropdown list. I don't know whether Laravel Excel or PHPSpreadsheet impose their own limits.

Comment: This does not work in Numbers, as the limit is 256 characters.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the example of export multiple columns with dropdown list from datalist taken from table and header having styling like bold and background color.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Category;
use App\Product;
use App\SKU;
use App\Tra_Tax;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStrictNullComparison;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\DataValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStyles;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;


class ProductExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithEvents, WithStrictNullComparison, WithStyles
{
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    protected $results;
    public function collection()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->type=="staff"){
            $this->id = $user->created_by;
        }else{
            $this->id = $user->id;
        }
        $this->results = $this->getProducts();
        return $this->results;
    }
    public function getProducts(){
        $product = Product::select('product_name','description','category','price','sale_price','quantity','sku',
        'sku_quantity','bar_code','tax','sold_by')
        ->where('created_by',$this->id)->where('status',1)->take(1)->get();
        $product[0]->category = Category::where('id',$product[0]->category)->pluck('name')->first();
        return $product;
    }
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
          'Product Name','Description','Category','Price','Sale Price','Quantity','SKU','SKU Quantity',
          'Bar Code','Tax','Sold By'
        ];
    }
    public function styles(Worksheet $sheet)
    {
        return [
             1    => ['font' => ['bold' => true]],
        ];
    }
    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
               
                //sheet object & no. rows
                $row_count = 50;
                $column_count = count($this->results[0]->toArray());
                $sheet = $event->sheet;

                //header color
                $sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle('A1:L1')
                ->getFill()
                ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
                ->getStartColor()
                ->setARGB('ADD8E6');

                //category dropdown
                $category = Category::where('created_by',$this->id)->pluck('name')->toArray();
                $validation2 = $sheet->getCell('C2')->getDataValidation();
                $validation2->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                $validation2->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation2->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation2->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation2->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation2->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation2->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation2->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation2->setPromptTitle('Pick from category list');
                $validation2->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation2->setFormula1('"' . implode(',',$category). '"');
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("C{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation2);
                }

                //sku dropdown
                $sku = SKU::where('created_by',$this->id)->pluck('unit')->toArray();
                $validation = $sheet->getCell('G2')->getDataValidation();
                $validation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
                $validation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation->setPromptTitle('Pick from sku list');
                $validation->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation->setFormula1('"' . implode(',',$sku). '"');
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("G{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation);
                }

                //tax dropdown
                $tax = 'A,B,C,D,E';
                $validation1 = $sheet->getCell('J2')->getDataValidation();
                $validation1->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                $validation1->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation1->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation1->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation1->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation1->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation1->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation1->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation1->setPromptTitle('Pick from tax list');
                $validation1->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation1->setFormula1('"' . $tax. '"');
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("J{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation1);
                }

                //sold by dropdown
                $sold_by ="each,weight";
                $validation2 = $sheet->getCell('K2')->getDataValidation();
                $validation2->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST );
                $validation2->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION );
                $validation2->setAllowBlank(false);
                $validation2->setShowInputMessage(true);
                $validation2->setShowErrorMessage(true);
                $validation2->setShowDropDown(true);
                $validation2->setErrorTitle('Input error');
                $validation2->setError('Value is not in list.');
                $validation2->setPromptTitle('Pick from sold by list');
                $validation2->setPrompt('Please pick a value from the drop-down list.');
                $validation2->setFormula1('"' . $sold_by. '"');
                for ($i = 3; $i <= $row_count; $i++) {
                    $event->sheet->getCell("K{$i}")->setDataValidation(clone $validation2);
                }

                //set size of column as per the length
                for ($i = 1; $i <= $column_count; $i++) {
                    $column = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($i);
                    $event->sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
                }
            },
        ];
    }
}
```