# excel drop down menu using Maatwebsite / Laravel-Excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-excel

I want export an excel file using Laravel-Excel package and want excel cell have drop down menu . now i do this for one cell of column but i want do this for all cell of column **except column title.**

```
 AfterSheet::class => function (AfterSheet $event) {

        /** @var Sheet $sheet */
        $sheet = $event->sheet;

        /**
         * validation for bulkuploadsheet
         */
        
        $configs ="DUS800, DUG900+3xRRUS, DUW2100, 2xMU, SIU, DUS800+3xRRUS,
        // DUG900+3xRRUS, DUW2100";
        $objValidation = $sheet->getCell('A2')->getDataValidation();
     
        $objValidation->setType(DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
        $objValidation->setErrorStyle(DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
        $objValidation->setAllowBlank(false);
        $objValidation->setShowInputMessage(true);
        $objValidation->setShowErrorMessage(true);
        $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);

        $objValidation->setFormula1('"' . $configs . '"');

    }
```

using this part of code `$objValidation = $sheet->getCell('A2')->getDataValidation();`  i can create drop down only for one cell of A column but i want do this for all cell of column A except column title. Thanks

> https://laravel-excel.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815227/laravel-excel-librarymaatwebsite-how-to-create-a-drop-down-list-in-exports
Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. I have used that answer  . but that did not use range for cell .