# phpexcel set cell value on drop down select

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

problem scenario:

I need to bulk insert data from excel to my database

Excel structure:

VendorId   |  VendorName  |  Products   |  Weights

[with vendorId, Products, Weights as drop-down]

I have two sheets one is **entry** and another is **data** sheet

in **data** sheet i managed to create data for dropdowns: VendorId, Products, Weights using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740108/phpexcel-multiple-dropdown-list-that-dependent#) code . And based on Products drop-down select i am able to select proper weights.

Now what i need is to select a vendorId based on the vendorId i need to set vendorName(a normal cell, which is not a drop-down), for this i can populate vendorName just like i have been doing for products->weights with addNamedRange where the range will be n:n since one vendorId is associated with one vendorName.

Secondly on selecting a different product from products drop-down i need to refresh the weights cell with any previous selected weights, if possible the first weight should get selected on products item change..

Comment: What I usually do is saving the Excel as .csv and writing a simple PHP script to convert the data. Not an answer but ...

Comment: i think before setting indirect i need to set the cell empty for second issue....but how do i have two command ... say emptycell+Indirect